# Filling 100 positions of memory with a result

Tags: assembly, 6502

I am trying to fill 100 positions of memory with a result of a previous operation in 6502 processor.

How can I increment the memory position stored in an register and store the result in it?

```
    *=0300

dato1 = $0A
dato2 = $0B
res = $0C
    LDA #4
    STA dato1
    LDA #5
    STA dato2
    ADC dato1
        STA res
    LDX #100
    LDY #res    
LOOP
    INY
    ; i have to fill 0C position and next 100 positions in this loop
    DEX
    BNE LOOP
```

Comment: Seems like you could use the `Absolute,Y` addressing mode for that (refer to your favorite 6502 instruction set reference and/or the manual for your assembler). Or if performance is important you could switch the registers around and use `Zeropage,X` addressing.

Comment: Thanks,finally I did it! With STA res,Y

Answer (score 1):

The 6502 has a 16 bit address bus, but only 8 bit accumulator/index registers, so pointers will not fit in a single register. To get around this limitation, 6502 programmers typically store little-endian pointers in zero page memory, and then use zero page indirect indexed operations to manipulate values at offsets from that address. here as an example that fills address 0x0200 to 0x0263 with the numbers 1,2,3,4,5,...,100 by putting the value 0x0200 in little-endian encoding at at the zero page address 0x00 and then iterating over the 100 bytes pointed to by that address using the y register.

```
LDA #$00
STA $00
LDA #$02
STA $01
LDY #$00
LDX #$01

loop:
CPY #$63
BEQ end
TXA
STA ($00),Y
INX
INY
JMP loop

end:
BRK
```